# Passing props to nested child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Here's my structure :

```
Main.js (Parent)
MainContainer.js
|
|_ Article.js
       |
       |__ Comments.js
```

Now i want to set click handler on **comment component (recursive component)** and dispatch an action.

here's my code on comment.js

```
class Comment extends Component {
    deleteComment = (id) => {
        this.props.handleDelete(id)
    }
    render() {
        var comment = this.props.comment
        return (
            <div className={styles.commentsWrapper}>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div className={styles.commentsName}>
                            <a onClick={() => this.deleteComment(comment.id)} className={styles.commentsNameRight}>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <p>{comment.body}</p>
                        {comment.children.length > 0 && comment.children.map(function(child) {
                            return <Comment comment={child} key={child.id}/>
                        })}

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Comment;
```

and Article.js :

```
 class Article extends Component {    

        handleDeleteComment = (id) => {
            this.props.deleteComment(id)
        }


        render() {
            return (
                <article className={styles.articleItem}>
                        {this.props.comments.map(item =>
                            <Comment handleDelete={this.handleDeleteComment} comment={item} key={item.id}/>)}
                </article>
            );
        }
    }


    export default Article;
```

And the Main.js

```
class Main extends Component {
    deleteComment = (id) => {
        this.props.deleteCommentRequest(id)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="">
                <Header />
                <section className="container">
                    <div>
                        {
                            !this.props.articles.loading && this.props.articles.articles? (
                                <div>
                                    {this.props.articles.articles.map(item =>
                                        <Article
                                        bodytext={item.selftext}
                                        key={item.id}
                                        comments={item.finalComments}
                                        deleteComment={this.deleteComment}
                                        />)}
                                </div>

                            ) : (
                                <div className={styles.loading}> <Spin /> </div>
                            )
                        }
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

so what i did here is: pass `deleteComment` as props from main to article and pass again `handleDelete` from article to comment.

not sure if it's a good way of doing this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is the Main component getting 'deleteCommentRequest' from? If it is a reduce action then you could directly access it from the comment component.

Comment: @RishiJodha can you tell me how ?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with this pattern for 2 - 3 depth of components, as that is how data should flow from children to ancestors. But if your application is getting heavier with several layers, consider a different state management such as redux where a global state is maintained and any component can subscribe to it and dispatch actions. More on that [here](https://redux.js.org/introduction/motivation).

Alternatively you can also achieve the same with React Hooks with `useContext` where you can set the context and any child component can subscribe to it. Example:

```
const MyContext = React.createContext();

export default function App({ children }) {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ items, setItems }}>
      {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}

export { MyContext };
```

Now in any child at any level of depth as long as it is within `App` component's children, you can do this:

```
import {MyContext} from './filename';

function TodoItem() {
  const { items, setItems } = React.useContext(MyContext);
  return (
    <div onClick={() => setItems(1)}>

    </div>
  );
 }
```

Comment: thanks, tbh i didn't get it, should learn about react hooks more.

Answer (score 1):

you can use context API to have the props in the wrapper and easily accessible from child component.

there is a great tutorial from wesbos on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLJN4JfniH4)

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyProvider>
        <div>
          <p>I am the app</p>
          <Family />
        </div>
      </MyProvider>
    );
  }
}


class MyProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    name: 'Wes',
    age: 100,
    cool: true
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Provider value={{
        state: this.state,
        growAYearOlder: () => this.setState({
          age: this.state.age + 1
        })
      }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </MyContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```